# how to get caption to ease in AND out on hover?

Tags: html, css

super beginner here. I'm trying to get an image caption to show on hover so I've set the opacity to 0 on the .caption class then 100% on the .caption:hover (not sure if this is best practice but it's the only way i could get it to work...)

Anyway, I'm now trying to get the caption to ease in & out on hover. I've tried adding **transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;** to both the .caption and the .caption:hover class. Adding it to the .caption:hover class makes it so it only eases in (then jumps straight back to its original state when i move my cursor away). Adding it to the .caption class works, however the caption shows briefly when I reload the page as well as when I hover over the image. I only want it to show on hover.

Any help would be appreciated!

CSS

```
.caption {
    opacity: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 318px;
    height: 318px;
    background: white;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.caption:hover {
    opacity: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="caption">
    <h2 class="artname">Caption 1</h2>
    <h3 class="artcategory">Caption2</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  visibility:hidden;
}

div:hover > p {
opacity:1;
visibility:visible;
}
div{
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately :( the ease out animation still occurs when I reload the page as well as when I hover over the image...

Comment: ok, I updated the snippet.  Let me know if this works for you.